# How to call function of one script to another script in webdriver selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest

I am trying to run unit test case of selenium webdriver in python on Pycharm, in which I am stuck on the problem.

I have two scripts i.e. **goodsRegister.py** and **Register.py**.
Now there is a function i.e.`test_Test2` in **goodsRegister.py** and I need that only and only that function to be executed in **Register.py**, not `test_Test1`.
Check the code

**goodsRegister.py** is as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import unittest
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


EmailEntry = input("Please Enter Email Address: ")
password='12345678'
class goodsweb(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        driverlocation ="/Users/new/Documents/Learning/Drivers/selenium-2.53.1/py/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverlocation
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverlocation)



    def test_Test1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        url = "https://goods.theentertainerme.com/"
        driver.get(url)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        self.RegisterButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='logs']/li[2]//a[text()='Sign up']")
        self.FirstName = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-firstname")
        self.Lastname = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-lastname")
        self.EmailAddress = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-email")
        self.CountryofResidence = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='register-form']//div[1]/div[4]//span")
        self.SelectCountry = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='registrationform-country_of_residence']")
        self.DateofBirth = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-date_of_birth")
        self.Gender = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='register-form']//div[1]/div[6]//div")
        self.Password = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-password")
        self.ConfirmPassword = driver.find_element_by_id("registrationform-confirmpassword")


        self.RegisterButton.click()
        self.FirstName.send_keys("Taimoor")
        self.Lastname.send_keys("Pasha")
        #self.EmailEntry = input("Please Enter Email Address: ")
        self.EmailAddress.send_keys(EmailEntry)


        self.CountryofResidence.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        Pakistan = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[17]/div/span//ul/li[175]")
        driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Pakistan)
        Pakistan.click()

        #selectCountry = Select(self.SelectCountry)
        self.DateofBirth.click()
        Month = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/div/select[1]/option[6]")
        Month.click()

        Year= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//div/select[2]")
        YearList = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']//div/select[2]")
        Year.click()
        SelectYear = Select(Year)
        SelectYear.select_by_visible_text("1990")

        DateofMY= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[5]/a")
        DateofMY.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        self.Gender.click()
        MaleGender= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[17]/div//span/ul/li[2]/span")
        MaleGender.click()
        self.Password.clear()
        #self.password='12345678'
        self.Password.send_keys(password)
        self.ConfirmPassword.clear()
        self.ConfirmPassword.send_keys("12345678")


        RegisterButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='register-form']//div[2]/input")
        RegisterButton.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        TitleDropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='user']/li[2]//a")
        newactions = ActionChains(driver)
        newactions.move_to_element(TitleDropdown).perform()
        SignOutButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='user']/li[3]/div/ul/li[5]/a")
        newactions.move_to_element(SignOutButton).click().perform()




    def test_Test2(self):

        driver = self.driver
        url = "https://goods.theentertainerme.com/"
        driver.get(url)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)


        self.LoginButton = driver.find_element_by_id("signin")
        self.LoginButton.click()

        self.LoginEmail = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sign_form-default']//div[1]/input[@type='email']")
        self.LoginEmail.clear()
        self.LoginEmail.click()
        self.LoginEmail.send_keys(EmailEntry)

        self.LoginPassword = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sign_form-default']//div[1]/input[@type='password']")
        self.LoginPassword.clear()
        self.LoginPassword.click()
        self.LoginPassword.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(5)
        self.LoginSubmitButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='sign_form-default']//div[3]/input")
        self.LoginSubmitButton.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        self.NameofUser = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='user']/li[2]//a[text()='Taimoor']")


        if self.NameofUser.text == "Taimoor":
            print("Title Matches")

        else:
            print("Name is invalid")






    def tearDown(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

and **Register.py** file is like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
import os
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import *
from goodsRegister import goodsweb

EmailEntry = input("Please Enter Email Address: ")
password='12345678'
class checking(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        driverlocation = "/Users/new/Documents/Learning/Drivers/selenium-2.53.1/py/selenium/webdriver/chromedriver"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = driverlocation
        self.driver= webdriver.Chrome(driverlocation)
        #self.driver= webdriver.Safari()

    def test_register(self):

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ =="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

But I am unable to do it so. Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Where are you initialising the variable which will store the object of  `goodsRegister.py`? you've imported it but you've never used it. Also, which file are you running? I presume you are running `Register.py` if so remove the `__main__` method in your other file.

Comment: If you have unit tests then you need to run **all** of your unit tests.